# How to build an app that will work with all Android versions?

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse when I export my project the app doesn't work on my device which uses Android 4.2. It gives me this message:

```
app has stopped
```

How to build an app that will work with all Android versions

Comment: "app has stopped".....that has nothing to do with the version. If it does not work because of the android version, you get a warning that it is not compatible. This seems to be a crash because of an error in your code. Add the stacktrace and relevant part of code...

Comment: and if you want to build an app that works on all versions, you need to adjust the minSdk and targetSdk, but that will limit the sources you can use. In reality, only, really only a view poeple will have devices with API lower than 4.1 (Jelly bean)....so I think it´s not neccessary to get lower....see here:https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: i use eclipse and the project show no errors . i used android 3.2 to build my project . can i change it to 4.1 ?

Comment: believe me, there is an error....if your app works on devices +4.4, then I guess you are using some method that is not available on lower versions. In Android Studio, this will never happen because you get a warning about that if you compile, you really should move to android studio. Eclipse will not be supported anymore, the ADT is dead. Anyway, adjust your filters in eclipse, remove every filter, then you will see the stacktrace.

Comment: Tidy up grammar, highlight error

Answer (score 0):

"app has stopped" seems to be a crash, if the app doesn't work on any device, she doesn't launch.
Use Debug to know what is the error or crash.

If you think that is a pversion problem, check in your gradle that you include sdk version for 4.2.

Comment: the app worked fine for devices with android +4.4 but for lower versions doesnt work

Comment: i tried it in my phone which is 4.2 i dont have an emulator. i used this line in code manifest <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: [2016-11-06 19:27:07 - apxx] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2016-11-06 19:27:07 - appxx] Device API version is 18 (Android 4.3)

Comment: i thinks you have to specify your sdkVersion in gradle and not in manifest

Answer (score 0):

[look at this page and table in part Requirements and Support](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)

as you see the version android you add by :

```
`cordova platform add android@8.1.0`
```

it can install on 4.4 - 9.0.0 version android and can not install on higher version.
for this issue you should build several app with different version android,may it help you!